# Problem accessing file from jar file in Java

Tags: classpath, java-io

I have a jar called App.jar and it's structure is as follows

```
App.jar
    |
    |
    |---xyzfolder
    |       |
    |       |--config
    |            |
    |            |--config.properties 
    |  
    | 
    |---com (contains classes)
          |
          |--MyClass.class
```

Now what I want is that I want to access **`config.properties`** file from **`MyClass.class`**

Comment: I've tried getClassLoader().getResources("config.properties") which gives nullpointerexception error.

Comment: Thats because you need to specify the path.  Its not in the same package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("classpath:/xyzfolder/config/config.properties");
```

see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29