# ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream not working when running on tomcat

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat

I am loading a configfile using ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream. The file is placed in the src folder of my GWT application. It ends up in `war/WEB-INF/classes`. 
I copy the `war` folder to tomcat under `webapps/MyApp`. When running the application, getSystemResourceAsStream throws an exception.
When running under Jetty it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream();
```

It will definitely work; I also had same type of problem.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789667/problem-accessing-file-from-jar-file-in-java) describes why you are having that problem.

Comment: Thanks... I am trying different solutions for more than 4 hours... this answer works for me...

Answer (score 1):

Try [`getClass().getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) instead. You need to call this method to access the class loader for your web application. The method you're calling uses the system class loader, which I believe is only going to contain the classes for the web container itself.

Comment: ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() is not a static method so I can not call it that way.

Comment: Updated answer, use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: What happens? Does it work under Jetty? Perhaps you can include in your question the relevant lines of code.

Comment: It works under Jetty. I think it throws and IOException under Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "relative/path" );
```

Note that relative/path is a path relative to war/WEB-INF/classes
E.g. if your file is war/WEB-INF/classes/resources/my.properties then use "resources/my.properties"